# Grafana Alert conditions

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, grafana, grafana-alerts

I created an alert that notifies me when I have unhealhy AWS load balancers. What I want is to use a regex so that I do not get notified when a preproduction load balancer is unhealthy. One idea is to filter on the LoadBalancerName variable.

I can do just that when creating a silence.

[image]

Do you know how I can do that when creating/editing an alert ? It seems filter doesn't have the regex option...

[image]

I would prefer not to rely on silences because I have to renew them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Isn't there any option to simply use `prep` with some "contains" operator? Note you do not need `.*` in a regex that does not have to match the entire string and `=~` does not require the whole string to match.

Comment: This is more cloudwatch question, than Grafana question. Can regex be even used as part of query to cloudwatch?

Comment: You can regex in notification policy as well.

Comment: Hi, thank all for your answers. Wiktor, it seems there's no contain operator... mark, why would that unable grafana from implementing a regex ? I'll use your tip Jan, thank you a lot !

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Jan Garaj, the solution is notification policies. I used a regex to not send the alerts to my slack channel.